# Issue on hibernate oneToMany with spring boot and postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, one-to-many

I have an issue with hibernate and postgres using spring boot.
When I run the application I see in postgres logs these errors(without any data bootstrap):

```
2021-06-25 13:55:31.057 UTC [81] ERROR:  constraint "uk_j1xiaxeat9b5r1qs27ei0t2a6" of 
relation "process_template_base_environmental_impact" does not exist
2021-06-25 13:55:31.057 UTC [81] STATEMENT:  alter table 
process_template_base_environmental_impact drop constraint 
UK_j1xiaxeat9b5r1qs27ei0t2a6
2021-06-25 13:55:31.062 UTC [81] ERROR:  constraint "uk_9568qjc94suvuskoi9o2li3er" of 
relation "process_template_elementary_flow_template" does not exist
2021-06-25 13:55:31.062 UTC [81] STATEMENT:  alter table 
process_template_elementary_flow_template drop constraint 
UK_9568qjc94suvuskoi9o2li3er
2021-06-25 13:55:31.064 UTC [81] ERROR:  constraint "uk_dy1ej2j9qxeoq6ca641tpfxr5" of 
relation "process_template_flow_template" does not exist
2021-06-25 13:55:31.064 UTC [81] STATEMENT:  alter table 
process_template_flow_template drop constraint UK_dy1ej2j9qxeoq6ca641tpfxr5
```

I have an entity called ProcessTemplate with ProcessTemplateId as compositeKey, and 3 cascades on ElementaryFlowTemplate, BaseEnvironmentalImpact, and FlowTemplate.

ProcessTemplate:

```
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Table(name = "process_template")
public class ProcessTemplate {
  @EmbeddedId
  @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
  private ProcessTemplateId id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "fk_process_base", referencedColumnName = "id")
  private ProcessBase processBase;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "fk_reference_flow_base", referencedColumnName = "id")
  private FlowBase referenceProduct;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Set<BaseEnvironmentalImpact> baseEnvironmentalImpacts;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @OrderBy("impactsContribute DESC" )
  private Set<FlowTemplate> flowsTemplate;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @OrderBy("impactsContribute DESC" )
  private Set<ElementaryFlowTemplate> elementaryFlowsTemplate;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "fk_source_info", referencedColumnName = "id")
  private SourceInfo sourceInfo;


  @Column(name = "version")
  @Version
  private Long version;
}
```

ProcessTemplateId:

```
@Embeddable
public class ProcessTemplateId implements Serializable {


  @Column(name = "process_base_id")
  private UUID processBaseId;

  @Column(name = "reference_product_id")
  private UUID referenceProductId;

  public ProcessTemplateId() {
  }

  public ProcessTemplateId(UUID processBaseId, UUID referenceProductId) {
      this.processBaseId = processBaseId;
      this.referenceProductId = referenceProductId;
  }

  public UUID getProcessBaseId() {
      return processBaseId;
  }

  public UUID getReferenceProductId() {
      return referenceProductId;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (this == o) return true;
      if (!(o instanceof ProcessTemplateId)) return false;
      ProcessTemplateId that = (ProcessTemplateId) o;
      return Objects.equals(getProcessBaseId(), that.getProcessBaseId()) &&
              Objects.equals(getReferenceProductId(), that.getReferenceProductId());
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
      return Objects.hash(getProcessBaseId(), getReferenceProductId());
  }

}
```

AbstractFlowTemplate:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class AbstractFlowTemplate {

  @Id
  @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
  private String id;


  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private FlowType flowType;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "fk_source_info", referencedColumnName = "id")
  private SourceInfo sourceInfo;


  @Column(name = "version")
  @Version
  private Long version;

}
```

ElementaryFlowTemplate:

```
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true, onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Table(name = "elementary_flow_template")
public class ElementaryFlowTemplate extends AbstractFlowTemplate {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_elementary_flow_base", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private ElementaryFlowBase elementaryFlowBase;

}
```

FlowTemplate (linkedProcessTemplate is not the bidirectional relation to ProcessTemplate but another unidirectional relation, because each flowTemplate had a link to another ProcessTemplate):

```
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true, onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Table(name = "flow_template")
public class FlowTemplate extends AbstractFlowTemplate {

     @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_flow_base", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private FlowBase flowBase;



    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "process_base_id", referencedColumnName = 
"process_base_id"),
    @JoinColumn(name = "reference_product_id", referencedColumnName = 
"reference_product_id")})
    private ProcessTemplate linkedProcessTemplate;

}
```

BaseEnvironmentalImpact:

```
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Table(name = "base_environmental_impact")
public class BaseEnvironmentalImpact {
    @Id
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private String id;

    private double value;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_methodology", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Methodology methodology;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_impact_category", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private ImpactCategory impactCategory;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_impact_indicator", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private ImpactIndicator impactIndicator;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_source_info", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private SourceInfo sourceInfo;

    @Column(name = "version")
    @Version
    private Long version;

    //ref
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_elementary_flow_base")
    private ElementaryFlowBase elementaryFlowBase;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(
                name = "process_base_id",
                referencedColumnName = "process_base_id"),
        @JoinColumn(
                name = "reference_product_id",
                referencedColumnName = "reference_product_id")
    })
    private ProcessTemplate processTemplate;
}
```

As I wrote I cannot understand why I had an errors log, probably I make a mistake in the relation or cascade but I'm not able to figure out the issue. If I import data they seem correctly inserted so I cannot understand the problem.
Thanks in advance for the help.

SOLVED, EDIT:

I solve only the error on ProcessTemplate-BaseEnvironmentalImpact adding a mappedBy.

I don't include a schema because I think it's autogenerated, I include these parameters in application properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
logging.level.org.hibernate = ERROR
spring.jpa.generate-ddl = true
```

I also solved other issues adding:

```
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "fk_pt_process_base_id", referencedColumnName = "process_base_id"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "fk_pt_reference_product_id", referencedColumnName = "reference_product_id")
} )
```

Comment: Hello, did you add constraint on your database? like foreign key because I suppose that error message is said there is no connection at all.

Comment: I don't understand, I use spring boot with hibernate and I think that the schema.sql is autogenerated, see the edit.